# jquery , get div with class name and chage text?

Tags: jquery, html, text, replace

Hello i want to change div text  but into div it has div again with same class

```
 <div class="ex"><div class="ex">this text must be change</div></div>
```

can you help me pls

Comment: "but into div it has div again" , what this means?? please explain.

Comment: `$('.ex').parent('div.ex').text('ex');`

Comment: `$('.ex .ex').html("New Text")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a css selector like this:

```js
$('.ex > .ex').html('changed.')
```

```css
.ex{color:red;}
.ex .ex{color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ex"><div class="ex">this text must be change</div></div>
<div class="ex">this text must be change</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Working Demo**

```js
$('.ex .ex').text('changed')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ex"><div class="ex">this text must be change</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.ex').parent('div.ex').text('ex');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ex">
  <div class="ex">this text must be change</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are wrong I guess. Look at your DOM structure after running your code snippet. The inner `div.ex` has been disappeared.

Comment: @JohnR the inner will be lost the OP didnt mention to retain the inner anyway. no mention of that anywhere in the OP

Comment: OP wants to change the text of that `div` alone. Query: `i want to change div text`

Comment: @JohnR which div?`Hello i want to change div text but into div it has div again with same class` there was no mention of `that div alone`